# angularjs Failed to instantiate module myLandingPage due to: when is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am using `ngRoute` to develop different templates and met this error:

> Failed to instantiate module myLandingPage due to:when is not defined.

I think I may make some mistakes with sequence of angular files, here is mine:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="resources/dirPagination.js"></script>
```

my angular module js file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myLandingPage', ['ngMaterial','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.caseInsensitiveMatch = true;
     $routeProvider.when('/table', {
         templateUrl: "table.html",
         controller: "mainController"
     })
     when('/dashboard', {
         templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
         controller: "mainController"
     })
     .otherwise({
         redirectTo:'/'
     })
});
myApp.controller('mainController',function($scope, $http){});
```

anyone know how to fix this bug? When is not defined?

Comment: is angularUtils.directives.dirPagination is a module?

Comment: could you please post the rest of the code?

Comment: thank you so much for reply. yes, angularUtils.directives.dirPagination is a module, which is a third party plugin for pagination, like ngMaterial, I add under the my.js I have updated in this quesion

Comment: The second `when` needs a dot in front of it: `.when`.

Comment: wow, thank you so much. Couldn't believe I made this mistake.